# How can multiple hash values be retrieved using perl?

Tags: perl, hash, reference, key

How can multiple hash values be retrieved? I tried using 
use Hash::MultiValue and get_all(). It throws an error saying "Can't call method "get_all" on an undefined value" . Which is the better option to implement this functionality of multiple values for a particular key ? The value of the key is the file that is being opened.

```
use warnings;
use List::MoreUtils qw(firstidx);
use Hash::MultiValue;

my $key_in;
…
open ($FR, "<$i") or die "couldn't open list";
 while($line=<$FR>){ 
   if($line =~ /search_pattern/){
   my $idx = firstidx { $_ eq 'hash_key' } @tags;   
   my $key= @tags[$idx+1];
   $hash{$key}= Hash::MultiValue->new($key=>'$i');
} 
close($FR);
for my $key_in ( sort keys %hash ) {
    @key_in = $hash->get_all('$key_in');
    print "$key_in = $hash{$key_in}\n";
}
my $key_in = <STDIN>;
if (exists($hash{$key_in})){
$hash_value = $hash{$key_in};
}else{
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the content of the input file `$i`? and the tags array `@tags`?

Comment: the file contains just test commands with various seeds and switches

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings;`. You are using `$hash` without having created such a var. This would have caught your error.

Comment: `'$key_in'` produces the string `$key_in`, which is surely not what you want!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can use `get_all()` from [`Hash::MultiValue`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Hash::MultiValue) to retrive multiple hash values for a given key:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);
use Hash::MultiValue;

my $hash = Hash::MultiValue->new();
$hash->add(tag1 => 'file1');
$hash->add(tag1 => 'file2');
$hash->add(tag2 => 'file3');
my @foo = $hash->get_all('tag1');
print(Dumper(\@foo));
```

**Output**:

```
$VAR1 = [
          'file1',
          'file2'
        ];
```

Comment: Of course, using Hash::MultiValue instead of a hash greatly slows down your program [without making it simpler](https://pastebin.com/VV1AqxF7)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried this way but when I pass one of the keys as an user input and then try to call the get_all method it gives an error "Can't call method "get_all" on an undefined value"  my $key_in=<STDIN>;  my @values = $hash->get_all('$key_in);

Comment: @user12401841 *"Can't call method "get_all" on an undefined value..."* Somehow `$hash` got undefined. Also you probably need to strip a trailing newline from `$key_in`. Can you provide a link to the complete code you tried?

Answer (score 2):

I think you want an array reference for the value. You can then treat that as an array. This is the sort of stuff we show you in [Intermediate Perl](http://www.intermediateperl.com):

```
 $hash{$key} = [];
 push @{ $hash{$key} }, $some_value;

 my @values = @{ $hash{$key} };
```

With Perl v5.24, you can use [postfix dereferencing](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2014/09/use-postfix-dereferencing/) to make it a bit prettier:

```
 use v5.24;

 $hash{$key} = [];
 push $hash{$key}->@*, 'foo';
 push $hash{$key}->@*, 'bar';

 my @values = $hash{$key}->@*;
```

And, since Perl automatically takes an undefined value and turns it into the reference structure you need (auto vivification), you don't need to initialize an undefined value:

```
 use v5.24;

 push $hash{$key}->@*, 'foo';
 push $hash{$key}->@*, 'bar';

 my @values = $hash{$key}->@*;
```

---

Get all the keys of a hash:

```
my @keys = keys %hash;
```

Get all of the values (in the order of the corresponding keys if you haven't changed the hash since you called `keys`):

```
my @values = values %keys;
```

Get some values with a hash slice:

```
my @some_values = @hash{@some_keys};
```

Get some keys and values (key-value slice):

```
use v5.20;
my %smaller_hash = %hash{@some_keys}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am using perl version - v5.14.1. I am able to print the hash key and value pairs. But when I am trying to give the key as an user input I am unable to get the value pairs.         $key_in=<STDIN>; my @some_values = @hash{@key_in};
print "hash value : @some_values\n";   This gives the array address instead of values.